# wpf shared ResourceDictionary file parameters?

Tags: wpf, styles, styling

if all Styles and Converters are stored in shared resource dictionary file (styles.xaml), and this file is used from various windows.

Is it possible, to pass a parameter to that file, and propagate that parameter to the converters?

I am looking for a way to pass a *"origin"* type parameter, so that the converters could be aware which place they are being used from? Just a hint of which window/grid is using the converter at the moment..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "converters" in a shared resource dictionary. When I see the term in the context of XAML and WPF I think of IValueConverter. Is it something else?

Comment: yes. iValueConverters. Convert has a optional parameter. i want to be able to pass it through resourcedictionary file

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this will work:

Add a reference to the System namespace in the declaration of each Window or UserControl where you want this.

```
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then in your resources section set things up like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <sys:String x:Key="WinConvertParam">IDTextForThisWindow</sys:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Your binding syntax could then look something like this:

```
{Binding SomeProperty, 
         Converter={StaticResource thatConverterIWrote}, 
         ConverterParameter={StaticResource WinConvertParam}}
```

...and your Convert or ConvertBack methods in your conversion classes then become aware of the Window that's using them, provided you vary the value of that `<sys:String/>` from file to file.

What do you think?